# Dynamic regexp_extract based on column value in spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to know if there is a way to implement dynamic regexp_extract in my dataset based on the column value.

For example:
if my column A value is "N06" I need to use regex as "(?<=2020:).*?\\n"

else if my column A value is "N02" I need to use regex as "(?<=2026:).*?\\n"

`ds.withColumn("extracted",functions.regexp_extract(functions.col("A"),regex,0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `when` and `otherwise` like this:

```
when(col("C") === "N06", regexp_extract(col("A"), regex1, 0))
  .otherwise(regexp_extract(col("A"), regex2, 0))
```